# Trying to append file to tar archive returns error "Cannot stat: No such file or directory"

Tags: command-line, tar

Just started using Linux and practising using different commands, as a learning exercise I was trying to append a file to a tar archive that I created named "test.tar" using this command:

```
tar rvf test.tar newfile
```

Which returned the error:

```
tar: newfile: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I also tried:

```
tar -rvf test.tar newfile
```

Which returned the same result.

Comment: You do not have any file in the current directory named "newfile"...

Comment: @psusi: See Below...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing:

```
echo I will not post any homework questions on Ask Ubuntu > newfile
```

and then try again as it looks like `newfile` doesn't exist. (which the command above creates)

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**